# Изобразить на комплексной плоскости множество точек, удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи в решении. Пытался положить `z = x + yi`, но в итоге не получаю пересечения, то есть:

```
Im (x + yi + 2i) < 0
Im (x + (y + 2)i) < 0
y + 2 < 0
y < -2
```

```
|z - i| < 1
|x + yi - i| < 1
|x + (y - 1)i| < 1
sqrt(x^2 + (y - 1)^2) < 1
x^2 + (y - 1)^2 < 1
```

В итоге получаем окружность с радиусом 1(то есть длина комплексного числа должна быть меньше 1, входить в эту область), а с предыдущего уравнения ясно, что `y < -2`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь непонятно, верно ли решение? Если да, то почему, если нет, то подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибся.

Answer (score 2):

решений для данной системы неравенств нет, что и показывает ваш график
т.е. на комплексной ничего изображать и не надо - пустой лист :)

Comment: То есть, решение моё верно? Сам алгоритм.

Comment: ну да, в конце только можно было бы сделать так: `x^2 + (y - 1)^2 < 1`, поскольку y < -2, то `x^2 + 9 < 1`, что x никак действительным быть не может, а значит решений нет, а графическая интерпретация верная